# plot_ly doesn't show data points on scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have aggregated my data set using the following line,

```
d3.aggr<-aggregate(cbind(TotalGreenhouseGases,Amount) ~ AssetName+Branch,data 
= d3.filter,FUN=function(d3.filter) c(mn =sum(d3.filter), n=length(d3.filter) ) )
```

and when i do a str(d3.aggr) i get the following result

```
'data.frame':   165 obs. of  4 variables:
$ AssetName           : chr  "Arts Centre - Meat Market" "Arts Centre - Nth   Melb Town Hall" "Arts Centre - Nth Melb Warehouse" "Arts Centre - Signal Box" ...
$ Branch              : chr  "Arts and Culture" "Arts and Culture" "Arts and Culture" "Arts and Culture" ...
$ TotalGreenhouseGases: num [1:165, 1:2] 30.29 23.7 1.15 4.17 4.43 ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : NULL
.. ..$ : chr  "mn" "n"
 $ Amount              : num [1:165, 1:2] 22.942 17.951 0.867 3.263 3.777 ...
 ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 .. ..$ : NULL
 .. ..$ : chr  "mn" "n"
```

and my data set looks like this,

[image: Screenshot for d3.aggr]

But when i try to plot it using plot_ly,

```
plot_ly(data = d3.aggr, x = Amount, y = TotalGreenhouseGases, mode = "markers",
    color = Branch)
```

I am getting no data points on my plot,

[image: resulting scatter plot]

And i get the following warning,

**Warning message:**
In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette Set2 is 8
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: based on the info you have provided, it should work.  Are there any `NA` in `BRANCH`?